# ReadableStream is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to encrypt some blobs in azure and I am using Streams API.
I am reading from a blob storage from a container and trying to push the blobs encrypted in other container.

Despite the fact that the instance of **new ReadableStream()** is recognized, I get logged the error "ReadableStream is not defined"
Any help on this, is more than welcome!

The code

```
const { BlobServiceClient } = require('@azure/storage-blob');
const openpgp = require('openpgp');
const {privateKey, publicKey} = require('./keys')


async function main() {

    const AZURE_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING = process.env.AZURE_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING;
    const blobServiceClient = BlobServiceClient.fromConnectionString(AZURE_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING);
    const containerClient = blobServiceClient.getContainerClient("uploadebs");
    const containerEncryptedFiles = blobServiceClient.getContainerClient("encrypted-dide");
    await containerEncryptedFiles.createIfNotExists("encrypted-dide")
    // RSA keys
    // console.log(`private key => ${privateKey}`)
    // console.log(`public key => ${publicKey}`)
    // .then((keyPair) => {console.log(`${JSON.stringify(keyPair)}` )}).catch((error) => console.log(`error in generating the keys: ${error}`));


    for await (const blob of containerClient.listBlobsFlat()) {

        if (blob.name.match('^DIDE*')) {
            const blockBlobClient = containerClient.getBlockBlobClient(blob.name);
            const encryptedblockBlobClient = containerEncryptedFiles.getBlockBlobClient(blob.name)
            const downloadBlockBlobResponse = await blockBlobClient.download(0);
            let blobData = await streamToString(downloadBlockBlobResponse.readableStreamBody)
            const readableStream = new ReadableStream({
                start(controller) {
                    controller.enqueue(blobData);
                    controller.close();
                }
            });
            const encrypted = await openpgp.encrypt({
                message: await openpgp.createMessage({ text: readableStream }), // input as Message object
                publicKeys: publicKey, // for encryption
                privateKeys: privateKey // for signing (optional)
            });
            console.log(encrypted);
            await encryptedblockBlobClient.upload(encrypted, encrypted.length)// the blob should be already crypted

        }
    }

}

async function streamToString(readableStream) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const chunks = [];
        readableStream.on("data", (data) => {
            chunks.push(data.toString());
        });

        readableStream.on("end", () => {
            resolve(chunks.join(""));
        });
        readableStream.on("error", reject);
    });
}

main().then(() => console.log('Done')).catch((ex) => console.log(ex.message));
```

package.json

```
{   .
    .
    .
    "dependencies": {
        "@azure/storage-blob": "^12.0.0",
        "@types/dotenv": "^4.0.3",
        "dotenv": "^6.0.0",
        "node": "^16.4.0",
        "openpgp": "^5.0.0-3"
    }
```

Complete code here [azure webjob to encrypt blobs into storage account with Node.Js](https://itnext.io/azure-webjob-to-encrypt-blobs-into-storage-account-with-node-js-90a0e43c6230)

Comment: `downloadBlockBlobResponse` is not a readable stream, you need to first make it a readable stream first.

Comment: @ApoorvaChikara, it think that's a stream as per Microsoft documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-nodejs#upload-blobs-to-a-container ("Download the previously created blob by calling the download method. The example code includes a helper function called streamToString, which is used to read a Node.js readable stream into a string."). 
The point is not this, I can see the definition of ReadableStream but I get the error that is not defined

Comment: But the stream from the Microsoft is different from Node.js one. I suggest you to use transform streams for such things, it might help.